# WordPress and template tags for Simple Fields plugin

Tags: plugin-simple-fields

I'm building a website using the [Simple Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-fields/) plugin to mark a post as featured and to add a simple slide show. I've read the documentation page and they only explain how to do things on the backend.

So I have some fields attached to a post, and now I want to get those values on the front-end.

How do I get those values?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that plugin just hooks into the meta fields so in order from them to display you can echo the get_post_meta.

For instance:

```
 <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_name_of_your_custom_field', true); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta